# presenting UITableViewController blocks UI

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to present a `UITableViewController` when a collectionViewCell is tapped. i've done this by using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath. When i press a collectionView Nothing happens and after i've pressed the UI is blocked and i cant do anything. No errors/log messages are shown. Why wont it present the viewController and why no error messages?

UITableViewController interfaceBuilder:

[image]

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    HomeProfileViewController *hpvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavProfile"];

    hpvc.idString= [[homesDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"idString"];
    hpvc.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    hpvc.imageArray = [imageDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [self presentViewController:hpvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why two times `hpvc.imageArray =`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that storyBoard is taking time to load. Maintain an instance level storyBoard object and do a lazy instantiation at `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Lazy instantiation code:

```
- (UIStoryboard *)storyboard: {
    if (!_storyboard) {
        _storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    }
    return _storyboard;
}
```

And in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
```

Again, this is my best guess. It is only deduced from the given code.